# Force UITableView to load cells before it is displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I need to force `UITableView` to load all cells based on datasource and get resulting `UITableView` height before it will be displayed on UI. I have other logic to be implemented based on that height. My rows have dynamic height and content inside cells is autolayouted. That is why I coudln't calculate it manually (or don't know how). It is crucial in my case to get the height before `UITableView` is displayed.

Please advise.

Comment: What is the minimum iOS version are you supporting? If iOS8+, use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` Otherwise, create a dummy version of the cell, force it to layout. Then in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` give the the height you calculated.

Comment: In tableview you don't forcefully load cell before it is displayed because tableview only load cell which is displayed on Screen. so you cant get height of your controller. you just manually calculate height.

Comment: You need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

**Now, the requirement is to find the height of cells with filled data**

*By this, you can find height of cells before displaying them on tableView*

Yes, you can do that by using below code:

```
/****/
- (CGFloat)heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier= @"IDENTIFIER";
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    static UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    });

    /**SET ALL DATA AND VALUES ON CELL*/

    CGFloat height = [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:cell];
//    NSLog(@"height at indexPath  %ld --> %f",(long)indexPath.row, height);

    return height;

}

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    CGFloat height = size.height;
    return height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```